# When does mysql throw an error instead of coercing text into the default column format?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm working with two mysql servers, trying to understand why they behave differently.

I've created identical tables on each:

```
| Field          | Type       | Collation         |
+----------------+------------+-------------------+
| some_chars     | char(45)   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| some_text      | text       | latin1_swedish_ci |
```

and I've set identical character set variables:

```
| Variable_name            | Value
+--------------------------+-------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                 
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                 
| character_set_database   | latin1                                               
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                               
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                 
| character_set_server     | latin1                                               
| character_set_system     | utf8
```

When I insert UTF-8 characters into the database on one server, I get an error:

```
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE7\xBE\x8E\xE5\x9B\xBD...'
```

The same insertion in the other server throws no error. The table just silently accepts the utf-8 insertion and renders a bunch of ? marks where the utf-8 characters should be.

Why is the behavior of the two servers different?

Comment: both servers same version? Maybe try using utf8m4b

Comment: Why aren't all those character sets the same?

Comment: @Andrew server versions are 5.6.23-log and 5.7.10. That might explain the difference, but I still feel like I'm missing an important configuration variable somewhere.

Comment: @EJP I'm pretty sure those are the default RDS character sets.

Comment: `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;` on both servers.  The results should be different, and in that difference should be where the answer will be found.  The difference isn't the MySQL server version *per se*, but the defaults values used with each version.

Comment: E7BE8E works equally well in both utf8 and utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

What command were you executing when you got the error?

- Your data is obviously utf8 (good).
- Your connection apparently is utf8 (good).
- Your table/column is declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`?  It should be utf8.

That is 美 - Chinese, correct?  Some Chinese characters need 4-byte utf8.  So you should use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` in all 3 cases listed above.

Other notes:
There is no substantive difference in this area in 5.6 versus 5.7.
@@SQL_MODE is not relevant.
`VARCHAR` is usually advisable over `CHAR`.